Is there a way to have Advanced Map Markers render in the map canvas instead of on top of it in the DOM?
Currently my team and I have been researching how to improve map performance using the Google Maps API for our software application. The app we are working on needs to support thousands of Markers and Polylines on the map at the same time. Through some trial and error we realized that the Legacy version of Markers can be rendered directly on the map canvas when the ​optimized​ flag is set to ​true​ and the ​draggable​ flag is not set on the marker. However, we also wanted to upgrade to Advanced Markers, but it appears that there is no way to get these markers to render on the canvas. For us, this results in Advanced Markers being significantly less performant than the legacy markers. Does anyone know of a way to get Advanced Markers to render in the canvas in the same way the legacy markers will?
One of the ways we tried getting Advanced Markers to render in the canvas was by not adding the gmpDraggable flag when creating the marker. However, this did not result in the markers being rendered in the canvas but still had them render on top of the canvas in the DOM.
I also asked this question in the Google Maps Help Community and was directed to ask this question here.
My original question: https://support.google.com/maps/thread/278589337?hl=en&sjid=3384645650526377507-NA

Could you please file a feature request in Google Issue Tracker?

For those searching for a solution to this problem, here is where the current issue lives on Google's Issue Tracker. Please vote that you are impacted if you would like to see this gain traction!
